# Losing ParseInstallation Device Token after crash in Parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for Android (version 1.10.1) to implement a chat APP.

Every time I login, I subscribed the chats channels list. The channels list is a atribute from the ParseInstallation class, as the device token. It works great, but when the APP crashes (any cause), it stops receiving GCM messages. It only returns to work if I uinstall the APP and install it again.

It seems like the device token become useless or broken.

Comment: What causes the crash?

Comment: In any crash type the APP have this  behavior.